# Why are open source projects so broken and apathetic if they are run by idealists?

Tags: software, project-management, community, documentation, philosophy

I've just wasted countless hours over weeks just trying to get LibreOffice to use a dark theme.

I've made numerous searches, looked through the entire UI, manually gone hunting for "the usual suspects" in terms of paths on the system, I've read the half-hearted installation instructions for the "Dracula" color scheme found online, I've read official manual pages that mention two different paths, both which do nothing when I place .soc files there, I've of course restarted the program itself and the machine many times, I've read questions and answers online that claim that you are supposed to use the paths mentioned, but these are not picked up/looked at/detected/cared about by LibreOffice, I've asked on Stack Exchange but nobody was able to answer, etc.

This is not the first time. In fact, this has been my consistent experience thousands upon thousands of individual times for all kinds of open source/free software over 20+ years now. Too many to even start listing them, but it was the same thing with Notepad++ and getting to to "understand" custom functions/constants.

It's always the same thing: if there is any documentation at all, it's grossly outdated and completely useless as a result. There is no help to be had. Even if somebody responds, or has written something online years ago vaguely related to the problem, they usually themselves don't know the answer. It truly is like nobody cares. But *why* do they not?

The obvious answer to this is that they aren't getting paid money, so why would they care? But if they are involved in a *non-profit project* in the first place, should they not know about this and actually care because they want it to be good? I don't understand why they just seem to like to pretend as if this is this fantastic, idealistic thing when in reality, nothing works and is just plain awful.

I would be paying for commercial software if I had money. It would've saved me so much headache and pain.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Folks contribute to open source projects for a variety of reasons – and their motivations might not align with your specific needs. Note that LibreOffice is not primarily developed by individual volunteers – about half of contributions come from for-profit companies like Collabora and RedHat (source: their 2020 annual report). In any case, LibreOffice seems to run in dark mode on my system, without having to configure anything.

Comment: even idealists don't have infinite free time

Answer (score 1):

I read your question as, "Why are free and open source projects difficult to use and lack documentation?" This is fundamentally a matter of the economics of available development resources, so I'll approach the question from this angle.

I agree with a comment above that people contribute to free and open source projects for a wide variety of reasons. A few of them include:

- they have a personal need for software that performs some specific functionality
- they think proprietary software is unethical and want to develop a replacement for some specific piece of proprietary software
- they are paid by their employer to improve a piece of open source software

I'd expect (without actual supporting data) that the first reason is the most common, if only because it's so easy for any developer to say, "I wish I had software that did X; I'll start writing it today." As [Eric S. Raymond says](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/homesteading/cathedral-bazaar/ar01s02.html), "Every good work of software starts by scratching a developer's personal itch."

It's easy to imagine free and open source software is developed in pursuit of an idealistic vision to create the perfect software, or to rid the world, once and for all, of proprietary software. Perhaps that's true for some deeply idealistic developers, but I'd say most people who write it (and even the idealists, when they're actually sitting down to put fingers to keyboards) are just trying to make software that is good enough to scratch their personal itches.

Of course, everyone has different needs, and the software as it exists may fail to meet those needs, or fail to properly document how to use it. The problems, from the perspective of developer, might be:

1. It's difficult to know what other people's problems are with your software/documentation, and
2. Once you do understand what problems exist, it's challenging to balance developer time between making the software that you planned to make against fixing deficiencies identified by others (or just balancing which of those externally-identified deficiencies to fix first!)

Documentation is an especially thorny problem to fix, because it's often "good enough" if you already have a sufficiently prerequisite good knowledge: if you already know how to make the software do X, or already know exactly where to look, or already know how to set environment variables, or already know how to set compiler flags, etc. Instead, it's great to write documentation that is complete, and accessible for a particular audience, and helps refer more novice users to the right prerequisite resources! That's what great technical writing can do, but not all developers are up to such a challenging task of technical writing, or aren't interested in spending what precious time they have on technical writing over the (more immediately-gratifying) task of writing code.

Obviously, this can leave users such as yourself in a very bad position! These pain points arise because the software might be able to do what you want -- and it will do it for the author and inner circle of developers who know how the software operates -- but they haven't taken sufficient care to make the software accessible to you, and outsider with whatever level of technical expertise you have. From such a position, it's easy to see how developers might laud the greatness of their software while simultaneously creating an environment in which it's difficult for others to use, as you identify in your question.

Once substantial advantage is that you have the ability to scratch you own personal itch here: if you wish to save others the pain of using the feature you've struggled to use, then you can write your own documentation and submit it for inclusion in the project. Or, if the feature doesn't yet exist, you (and, perhaps anyone else who want to participate in your crowdfunding effort) can pay someone to modify the source code and make it exist.